# 403 error while deleting Custom post type using rest api

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, wordpress-rest-api

```
deleteNote()
  {
    $.ajax({
      beforeSend: (xhr) => {
        xhr.setRequestHeader('X-WP-Nonce', universityData.nonce)
      },
      url: universityData.root_url + '/wp-json/wp/v2/note/98',
      type:'DELETE',
      success:(response) => {
        console.log('congrats');
        console.log(response);
      },
      error:(response) => {
        console.log('sorry');
        console.log(response);
      }
    });
  }
```

I'm trying to delete a custom post type using rest api currently I've hard coded the id of the note [image]

I've also setup the nonce but it still says forbidden, What should I do in this case. Please advice.

Edit: This is the response text "`responseText: "{\"code\":\"rest_cookie_invalid_nonce\",\"message\":\"Cookie check failed\",\"data\":{\"status\":403}}`"
"

Comment: Have you tried to disable mod_security and/or caching plugin (if any)?

Comment: I'm not using any plugin only ACF, Members are installed

Comment: Try login/out, or a different browser to check if cookie/nounce is outdated?

Comment: Okay I think I got it, wp_create_nonce('wp_rest'); I missed this argument "wp_rest"

Comment: This is not an issue with your JS code. This is a WordPress Issue, you should have a look on your server side